# Why would a model instance not be found when committing count using write-behind or sharded counters in App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm working on a counter for an App Engine application and am following the example outlined here http://blog.notdot.net/2010/04/High-concurrency-counters-without-sharding

I'm having trouble understanding the need for the following lines:

```
counter = cls.get_by_key_name(name)
if not counter:
  counter = cls()
```

It seems an increment was requested for the instance, and then when that increment was to be applied to the datastore, the instance couldn't be found and was replaced with a new one.

The same pattern is used on the Sharding Counters example code.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters.html

```
counter = SimpleCounterShard.get_by_key_name(shard_name)
    if counter is None:
        counter = SimpleCounterShard(key_name=shard_name)
```

In this case, the key_name is consistent between the one that wasn't found and the one that is created, so when counter.put() is eventually called it seems the new one will overwrite the not-found one.

My usage is similar to this example, which is based off the first example above: https://github.com/pamelafox/ragetube/blob/master/models.py

I'm reading line *66* as "a song was viewed and it's time to update its viewcount.  Fetch the song, but if you can't, create a new song and give it this count".  That can't be right.

Why would get_by_key_name() fail to return a record? Is there some default behavior that makes the first example work (ie, should a key_name of some kind be supplied)?  What situation might I find myself in if I simply returned from the function if the instance couldn't be found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one should be

```
counter = cls(key_name=name)
```

Comment: Thanks, Greg. The examples might have accidentally omitted that. Any idea why you'd need to do this in the first place, though? (ie, why would get_by_key_name() return None - presumably a caller in the recent past requested an increment on this counter, so it should exist)

Comment: In that code example, the counter is *just* a counter, so it's not going to exist prior to the first time someone tries to increment it. In your code, you're adding the count to something that presumably has to exist before it can be viewed, so the check is probably unnecesary.